# black 50px shadow starting at opacity 1 and finishes with opacity 0 (gradually)

Tags: html, css

How can we add a black shadow to a background image, shadow starting at opacity 1 and gradually decreasing to opacity 0, on all 4 sides of the image? (At least 50 pixels worth of "decreasing shadow opacity". box-shadow offers only a small amount of shadow in which the opacity goes down gradually.)

I've tried playing around with `mask-image`, for example: `-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 85%, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));`

This creates the desired shadow but only at the bottom of the image, not sure if this could be used to create it on the other 3 sides.

Edit: The shadow should be inside (I believe inset if box-shadow)

The goal of this will be to make our users' cover photos look good on our website's black background, even if they have brighter photos. The shadow inside the image should help the image blend in with the site's black background.

Comment: box-shadow is your friend. If you start a plunker you'll get better feedback.

Comment: "not sure if this could be used to create it on the other 3 sides" — have you _tried_ it? using combinations of left/right/top/bottom?

Comment: Playing around with it, still in vain.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x200);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Wait, wait....a voice is telling me the background of the page is a dark, dark, color. The shadow should be on the inside of the element, start from the darkest of darks and fade *into* the image, like this...

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x200);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 20px #000000 inset;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

What's that? Whoa, hold up... I'm sensing the `box-shadow` should go super, super deep... like this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x200);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px 50px #000000 inset;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

;)

Sounds like the mind-reading is still off. So here's a final example using a `linear-gradient`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0%, #000000 70%, #000000 100%), url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x200);
  background-size: cover, cover;
  background-position: center center, center center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can this be inside?

Comment: hm, it's too light for our use. It becomes light very quickly after just several pixel, for example there's not much difference between 40px and 100px. We really need something that starts black for several pixel at say 1 opacity, then goes to 0.9 for a few pixels, then 0.8, and so on until 0, on each side like box shadow.

Comment: Wish I was a psychic and could read minds, but I'm not. You'll have to provide an image, or experiment with the different `box-shadow` properties to get the desired effect you want. I've updated the solution in my best mind-reading attempt.

Comment: It was made clear: "starting at opacity 1 and finishes with opacity 0 (gradually)". But the code you've given "becomes light very quickly after just several pixel, for example there's not much difference between 40px and 100px".

Comment: @DanP. Please, provide an image.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to use the CSS3 `box-shadow` property with the `inset` marker.  This will pop a shadow inside a container or element (similar to what is sometimes called a *vignette* in image editors) which adheres to the element's proportions, so it might not be what you're after.

**Ex. HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Ex. CSS**

```
#container {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url(path/to/image.jpg);
    background-size:cover;

    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 50px #000000;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 50px #000000;
}
```

Playing with the vertical and horizontal offset values (here set at 0) may produce more effective results, for example something like this ...

```
width: 200px;
height: 200px;

box-shadow: inset 0 100px 50px -25px #000000;
```

... will give the impression of a vertical gradient, top-2-bottom, dark-2-light.

As always, there's a great explanation of the `box-shadow` property over [@ CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/).

Hope that helped.  :)